# Look up in other rows for missing matches in a row (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, row, vlookup

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['widget1', 'widget1', 'widget1', 'widget2', 'widget2', 'widget3', 'widget3', 'widget4'],
               'group': ['group1', 'group1', '', 'group1', '','group2', '', '']})
```

and want to output this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['widget1', 'widget1', 'widget1', 'widget2', 'widget2', 'widget3', 'widget3', 'widget4'],
               'group': ['group1', 'group1', '', 'group1', '','group2', '', ''],
               'new group': ['group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group1','group2', 'group2', '']})
```

So that a new column is created that:

- populates over values from the 2nd column if not nan
- for nan, a look up is made against the corresponding value in the first column and any match for that first column value in any other row where that value has a match with column 2 and, if so, pull in that value into the new column
- if none found, leave as null

Any help on this would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this set of codes:

```
import numpy as np

df1['group'][df1['group'] == ''] = np.nan          
df1['new group'] = df1.groupby('product')['group'].ffill().bfill()   
df1[['group', 'new group']] = df1[['group', 'new group']].fillna('')
```

Output result:

```
   product   group new group
0  widget1  group1    group1
1  widget1  group1    group1
2  widget1            group1
3  widget2  group1    group1
4  widget2            group1
5  widget3  group2    group2
6  widget3            group2
7  widget4
```

The codes work as follows:

1st line:  Temporarily set empty string in column `group` to `nan`

2nd line:  Group the rows by the same `product` groups.  Then for each group with same `product`, look into the column `group` and perform both forward fill and backward fill to fillup any `nan` values with non-nan values anywhere in both directions within the group.  The resulting Series of data (with null values now filled-up as far as possible) is copied to the new column `new group`.

3rd line:  reset the empty strings previously translated to `nan` back to empty string.  If other columns in your original dataframe does not contain `nan` values, you can simplify this line of code to `df1.fillna('')`

Note that these codes assumed for every product, there can only be one possible value of group value (if any).  If there can be 2 or above, the forward fill and backward fill operations may get different values depending on the positions of the multiple non-null group values.

Comment: Great answer! Thank SeaBean!